# Different configurations for MicroService from Spring Configuration Server

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config, spring-profiles

I have a Spring Configuration Server Running as Microservice, On Stratup it loads the config file from the Git Repository according to the profile:

For Example **foo** profile loads **application-foo.yaml** from the configured Git Repository.

How i Run this Config Server Service with multiple profiles ? Then according to the Spring profile of the Spring Service Client (using the config server above) i could retrieve the right profile for my service instance.

For Example i can Run a service with **bar** as value for **spring.active.profile** the it will get the **application-bar.yaml** from the Git Repository ?

I have done some tests, and it seems the config server load only one Git Conf Repository, and no matter the spring active profile value used by my Service (targeting the Config Service ) it always loads the **application-foo.yaml**.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: yes, that's exactly how it works

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but how it's possible when the config spring server starts loading one property file "application-foo.yaml" from the Git repo corresponding to the spring active profile ? maybe i miss something  ( i want to call another profile to load another GIt Repo from the same Spring cloud server instance )

Comment: I don't understand your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my problem.

Using Pattern Matching and Multiple Repositories by [Official Spring Cloud Server Doc](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/reference/html/#_pattern_matching_and_multiple_repositories)

My Client call my server config by this request : `serverurl/{application}/{profile}` then it fetchs a pattern corresponding to the {profile} in this path *spring > cloud > config > server* once pattern matchs it load the right config files from the founded Git Repo.